# WSO2 API Manager Version 4.1.0 - 404 Error Issue and Troubleshooting

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 version 4.1.0 and have installed it on 2 servers, sharing the same MS SQL DB. Everything is working normally; however, today when clients called the WSO2 API, it reported a 404 - Not Found error. I checked the logs in carbon.log and api.log, both of which indicated 'Not found API.' After that, I restarted the service, and everything returned to normal.

Has anyone encountered a situation like mine? And how did you solve and troubleshoot this error?

Here are the parameters in my deployment.toml:

```
[server]
hostname = "*.*.*.*"
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
server_role = "default"
[super_admin]
username = "*"
password = "*"
create_admin_account = true
[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"
#mssql database
[database.apim_db]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://*.*.*.*:1433;databaseName=WSO2AM_INT_DB_V4;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true"
username = "**"
password = "*"
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
[database.shared_db]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://*.*.*.*:1433;databaseName=WSO2_SHARED_INT_DB_V4;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true"
username = "**"
password = "*"
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
[database.stats_db]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://*.*.*.*:1433;databaseName=WSO2_STATS_INT_DB_V4;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true"
username = "**"
password = "*"
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
provider = "wso2"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://*.*.*.*:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://*.*.*.*:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://*.*.*.*:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://*.*.*.*:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://*.*.*.*:${https.nio.port}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://*.*.*.*:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://*.*.*.*:8021"
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default"]
[apim.analytics]
enable = false
auth_token = ""
[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://*.*.*.*:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
[apim.devportal]
url = "https://*.*.*.*:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_credentials = false
[apim.throttling]
service_url = "https://*.*.*.*:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://*.*.*.*:5672"]
[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://*.*.*.*:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://*.*.*.*:9711"]
[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]
[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"
#mssql database
[database.local]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://*.*.*.*:1433;databaseName=WSO2_CARBON_INT_DB_V4;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true"
username = "**"
password = "*"
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://*.*.*.*:${mgt.transport.https.port}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"
[oauth.grant_type.token_exchange]
enable = true
allow_refresh_tokens = true
iat_validity_period = "1h"
# Enabling Zipkin Tracing
[apim.open_tracer]
remote_tracer.enable = true
remote_tracer.name = "zipkin"
remote_tracer.properties.hostname = "*.*.*.*"
remote_tracer.properties.port = "9411"
# Enabling follow comment WSO2
[apim.event_hub]
enable = true
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
service_url = "https://*.*.*.*:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
event_listening_endpoints = ["tcp://*.*.*.*:5672"]
```

Sincerely thank you all for your advice.